# how to show 1 div out of 4 at a time

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, frontend

So I have a navigation of 4 links, to 4 divs(pages).
I want only one page to show at a time, with the id=home showing first once the page loads.

To be clearer, when I click on the "withdraw" link, the only page that would be visible should be the div id="withdrawal"

HTML:

```
    <!--navigation-->
     <div class="col nav">
      <ul>
       <li class="nav-item nav-li">
        <div class="py-3">
    <a href="#" class="" id="" aria-current="page" title="Home" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="right" onclick="openPage(); return false;">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-house-user bi"></i>
      <p>Home</p>
    </a>
  </div>
</li>
<li class="nav-item nav-li">
  <div class="py-3">
    <a href="#" class="" id="defaultOpen" aria-current="page" title="Profile" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="right" onclick="openPage(); return false;">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-house-user bi"></i>
      <p>profile</p>
    </a>
  </div>
</li>
<li class="nav-item nav-li">
  <div class="py-3">
    <a href="#" class="" id="defaultOpen" aria-current="page" title="Deposit" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="right" onclick="openPage(); return false;">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-house-user bi"></i>
      <p>deposit</p>
    </a>
  </div>
</li>
<li class="nav-item nav-li">
  <div class="py-3">
    <a href="#" class="" id="defaultOpen" aria-current="page" title="Withdrawal" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="right" onclick="openPage(); return false;">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-house-user bi"></i>
      <p>withdraw</p>
    </a>
  </div>
</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
      <!--end of navigation-->
       <!--Pages-->
      <div class="tabcontent col" id="home">
        <div class="text-center bg-black">
         <h3 class="">HomePage</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tabcontent" id="profile">
        <div class="text-center bg-primary">
         <h3>Profile</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tabcontent" id="deposit">
        <div class="text-center bg-danger">
         <h3>Deposit</h3>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="tabcontent" id="withdrawal">
        <div class="text-center bg-warning">
         <h3>Withdrawal</h3>
        </div>
     </div>

     <!--End of Pages-->
```

CSS:

```css
.tabcontent{
    display: none;
    color: white;
}
```

JS:

```
    <script>

function openPage() {
  // Hide all elements with class="tabcontent" by default */
  var i, tabcontent;
  tabcontent = document.getElementsByClassName("tabcontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabcontent.length; i++) {
  tabcontent[i].style.display = "none";
}

 // Show this tab content on page load
 document.getElementById("home").style.display = "block";
}
 


  </script>
```

I don't mind any jqueries answers too, so long as it works fine.

Comment: Hi 

Can you specify what isn't working?

Comment: *"would be visible should be the"* ...the?

Comment: STOP using unsafe inline `onclick` attribute handlers. JS should be in one place only, and that's the respective tag of file. Use addEventListener() instead.

Comment: @BentOnCoding none of the pages is showing even after clicking any of the links.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan i've fixed that

Comment: Also, if you need *buttons*, than use `<button type="button>"`! `<a>` anchors are used for navigation, not as UX elements that toggle some elements visibility.

Comment: `id="defaultOpen"` multiple times on a single page? Oh, nono. ID should be **unique**.  Use class instead.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan give me one real life example why it's unsafe, please. I mean in opposite to **not** inline.

Comment: @FlashThunder You want one? XSS and Content Security Policy implementation. Also, you'd never want to debug such an application. Same goes for `style` tags. (We're not W3Schools). Another reason: as soon an external (oddly coded) 3rd party application attaches to your DOM and for some reason assigns `on*` handlers, or novice programmers taking `on*` for granted; any other eventName in the on* name-scope will override the previous one. There's only **one** valid way to use `on` handlers, and that's from a JS file, and when creating Elements from in-memory and attaching them to the DOM.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan none of these are real life examples and most of them are just "maybe" or harmless... I would like to get a real life example of how danger it is. It's not that I am arguing, but this ... ok I am arguing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a function what hide every `div` with class `.tabcontent`.
I added to every `a` an evenListener to find the .tabcontent `div` with the same `id` what to the a `data-target` is given.
That will be changed the style to `block`, tho other `div` has `style: none`.

```js
const links = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("a"));
const tabs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".tabcontent"))

const hideAll = () => tabs.forEach((tab)=>tab.style.display = "none");
hideAll();

links.forEach((link)=>{
  link.addEventListener("click", (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    hideAll();
    tabs.filter(tab => tab.id === link.dataset.target)[0].style.display = "block";
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="col nav">
      <ul>
       <li class="nav-item nav-li">
        <div class="py-3">
    <a href="#" class="" id="" aria-current="page" title="Home" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="right" data-target="home">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-house-user bi"></i>
      <p>Home</p>
    </a>
  </div>
</li>
<li class="nav-item nav-li">
  <div class="py-3">
    <a href="#" class="" id="defaultOpen" aria-current="page" title="Profile" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="right" data-target="profile">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-house-user bi"></i>
      <p>profile</p>
    </a>
  </div>
</li>
<li class="nav-item nav-li">
  <div class="py-3">
    <a href="#" class="" id="defaultOpen" aria-current="page" title="Deposit" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="right" data-target="deposit">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-house-user bi"></i>
      <p>deposit</p>
    </a>
  </div>
</li>
<li class="nav-item nav-li">
  <div class="py-3">
    <a href="#" class="" id="defaultOpen" aria-current="page" title="Withdrawal" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="right" data-target="withdrawal">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-house-user bi"></i>
      <p>withdrawal</p>
    </a>
  </div>
</li>
  </ul>
 </div>
      <!--end of navigation-->
       <!--Pages-->
      <div class="tabcontent col" id="home">
        <div class="text-center bg-black">
         <h3 class="">HomePage</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tabcontent" id="profile">
        <div class="text-center bg-primary">
         <h3>Profile</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tabcontent" id="deposit">
        <div class="text-center bg-danger">
         <h3>Deposit</h3>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="tabcontent" id="withdrawal">
        <div class="text-center bg-warning">
         <h3>Withdrawal</h3>
        </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: There's no need for `Array.from(` unless you're targeting defunct IE browsers. NodeList has already the `forEach` Method prototype.

Comment: @exphoenee Nice. It works. But I need the "id=home" to be displayed first when the page loads

Answer (score 1):

If you just want it to work and you don't care how, consider Bootstrap.
Why reinvent the wheel?

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- JavaScript Bundle with Popper -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#home" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</button>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#profile" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</button>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
    <button class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-bs-toggle="tab" data-bs-target="#contact" type="button" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</button>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">Home</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">Profile</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">Contact</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want 1 of x elements to show, I'd suggest using a switch statement in a function, or contain the element inside of an object that also has a "isSelected" property to know which one to show when iterating through.

eg with switch:

```
let links = ['home', 'profile', 'deposit', 'withdrawal']    // in practise use variable references to the element, preferably by id since the nav won't be changing

const displayDiv = (whichdiv)=>{
    switch(whichdiv){
        case 'home':    // use elements, not strings, this is just for demonstration purposes
            return homeDiv  // the div you want to be shown, returning this will let you append just the one you want to show to the container it sits in
        case 'profile':
            return profilediv
        case 'deposit':
            return depositDiv
        case 'withdrawal':
            return withdrawalDiv
    }
}

const clickhandler = (evt)=>{
    evt.preventDefault()
    let whichIsSelected = displayDiv('home')    // whichIsSelected is now the element you want to be shown
    // remove any div inside the container, then append whichIsSelected to the container
}
```

The way I'd prefer is with an object containing both the div and whether or not it is selected, then contain all of those objects in an array so you can iterate through them all and make sure the ones that aren't selected have their property changed to false when another one is changed to true. For eg:

```
let contentContainerDiv = getElementById('content-container-div')
let home = getElementById('home-div')
let profile = getElementById('profile-div')
let deposit = getElementById('deposit-div')
let withdrawal = getElementById('withdrawal-div')
let objhome = {
    page: home,
    isSelected: true    // default set to home
}
let objprofile = {
    page: profile,
    isSelected: false
}
let objdeposit = {
    page: deposit,
    isSelected: false
}
let objwithdrawal = {
    page: withdrawal,
    isSelected: false
}
let pages = [objhome, objprofile, objdeposit, objwithdrawal]

function clickHandler(evt){
    evt.preventDefault()
    pages.forEach( v => v.isSelected = false)
    this.isSelected = true
    loadPageThatsSelected()    
}

function loadPageThatsSelected(){
    let selected = pages.filter( v => v.isSelected )
    contentContainerDiv.removeChild(contentContainerDiv.firstChild)
    contentContainerDiv.appendChild(selected.page)
}
```

Either way, I strongly recommend using unique id's and variable references to those id's

Comment: There's a huge difference b/w `let` and `const`

Comment: lol it's an example to show the thought process, clearly it's not refactored code. There are too many ways to approach a solution all based on the final end product of the site so a full answer would be needlessly wordy and switching let/const would be a distraction to the answer imho